# Enzyme adaptor - TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tag' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am updating our dependencies and seem to run into an issue when upgrading html-react-parser to 1.2.7. I am using react 17.0.2 and `@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17` (0.6.2). If I don't upgrade the package all the tests run fine. If I update that package to the latest version I get that error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tag' of undefined` I am not sure what I would need to do to get around this.

The error is pointing to this line in my code `import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';`

I can downgrade package and still works.

```
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
```

and call it like so just like the docs:

```
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Has anyone got any ideas?

Edit:

Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tag' of undefined

  2 | // This is made by one of the contributers
  3 | // eslint-disable-next-line simple-import-sort/imports
> 4 | import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
    | ^
  5 | import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
  6 | import { format } from 'util';
  7 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/domhandler/lib/node.js:32:35)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/domhandler/lib/index.js:15:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/index.js:31:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/lib/parse.js:4:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/lib/static.js:13:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/index.js:8:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/Utils.js:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/index.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17/src/ReactSeventeenAdapter.js:30:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17/src/index.js:1:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/javascript/src/test/setupTests.js:4:1)
```

Comment: Show the full error stack

Comment: That is the full error stack unfortunately.

Comment: Ive added the stack for you @slideshowp2